# What was the prevalence of ethnic minorities in 15th century Bohemia?

Tags: 15th-century, ethnicity, bohemia, population

What was the prevalence of what we in contemporary western culture would consider "ethnic minorities" (Africans, East Asians, South Asians, Latinos, etc) in the population of early 15th century Bohemia? I have heard various conflicting reports on this topic; general consensus seems to be that there were none of what we today would consider minorities in that region during that period, but some people who disagree are citing [this article](http://medievalpoc.tumblr.com/post/75048606179/hi-ive-been-looking-at-a-kickstarter-for-a) as proof of the contrary.  I am not sure whether this source is credible and would like some clarification on the actual facts.

Comment: Might want to rewrite to remove the anachronisms.

Comment: @twosheds They are not from any source in particular, i have just been told different things by different people.

Comment: who chats about ethnic minorities in the population of early 15th century bohemia? and to have multiple people chat about it?

Comment: @Himarm https://twitter.com/android927/status/570314353943183360

Comment: so essentially your argument on twitter is if there were black people in bohemia in the 1400s? just from its geographical location, im going to hazard and say if there were any at all, it would be no more then a couple, and most likely traders.

Comment: or people with spanish decent since there was a sizable african/spanish population due to the muslim conquest of most of spain a hundreds of years earlier. it was far more likely that these people of african decent would have interacted with bohemia then persons directly from africa.

Comment: @Himarm Just to clarify, its not actually my argument. I came across it and saw that it was basically going nowhere, so i figured that posting the questing here may help to settle the dispute.

Comment: First, I laughed when I read at @Himarm's comment, then laughed again to find out someone actually was chatting about ethnic minorities in early 15th century Bohemia. Secondly, reading that thread really changes how I interpret your question. I would have assumed you were asking about the distribution of Slavs, Germans, Magyars, etc.

Comment: @twosheds I have edited the question for clarity

Comment: @twosheds - I guess these days ethnic and minority have only one meaning. Although usually Asians are excluded from such lists.

Comment: In 15th century, Asia was what you would call "The first world". So I doubt there were "immigrants" from Asia there. Bohemia wasn't exactly a trading hotspot either unlike let's say Constantinople to attract trading communities. As for African people, that was the time when Spanish reconquesta was nearing its completion and many people of Moorish, Arab, Berber descent were being forcibly converted by the Catholic Monarchs of Iberia. So it is plausible that some of those Moriscos may have ventured further inside Europe but it is unlikely except in very small numbers

Comment: Any ethnic minorities in Bohemia at that time would have to be Europeans from neighboring states of German HRE duchies, Poland, Hungary, Refugees from Balkans fleeing from expanding Ottoman Empire. Altaic converts from former Mongol territories in Russia may have been present as well (they were present in Poland for certainty). Exodus of Arabs from Sicily was completed 2 to 3 centuries before that and they were dispersed in Italy IIRC, not central Europe.

Comment: Downgrading from an answer to a comment. How many people in medieval Bohemia would we now consider to have been "people of color" is an interesting, though difficult question to answer; medieval Europeans wouldn't frame the question of ethnicity as we do. [medievalpoc's blog](http://medievalpoc.tumblr.com/) is that of an art historian, so doesn't really speak to demographics, beyond showing evidence that there were enough people of color around for artists to use them as models and paint their likenesses.

Comment: Emperor Sigismund used his Hungarian army to deal with his personal Bohemian disputes in the beginning of XV c. One detail shown in the Kingdom Come Deliverance game is that part of his army were Cumans who had migrated to Eastern Hungary. You could investigate if the game is correct on depicting Cumans - and if the Hungarian speakers called 'Cumans' in the game actually existed and  were descendants of the Asian people called Cumans. It would not be strange if a few Cumans remained in Bohemia after the war.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer this question. The first mention from Arab merchant Ibráhím ibn Jákúb who notes: Prague is made of stone and lime and one of the biggest cities to trade (965-966,https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibr%C3%A1h%C3%ADm_ibn_J%C3%A1k%C3%BAb). In 1348 the king Charles the fourth was elected as Bohemian king after his father Johann von Luxemburg. He tried to make Prague, our capital city, a center of trade. He founded the university which is now called after him (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_IV,_Holy_Roman_Emperor).

In those days in Bohemia were some of those minorities – Jews, Gypsies.  After Charles the fourth died (1378) his son Wenceslaw the fourth took his place (approximately around 1403). He was as good as his father.

The center of trade declines. Then the reformation of religion started. Our reformator Jan Hus preached about catholic priest bureaucracy
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hussites, that all for political situation).

To make it clear there are not such evidance that there was an actually minority of black people in medieval history of my country (https://blisty.cz/art/73195-nikdy-se-nikdo-takovy-v-ceskych-dejinach-nevyskytoval.html). The symbols usually of black collered people represent something bad ( black woman- ugly, stinky; a groupe of black guys with steel sticks- falus symbol at so on). A discovery of man with negroid sight was foun in Prague historian Petr Charvát claims that the man was part of mission of Saints Cyril and Methodius. Another typical thing was a black kid as toy ( bought at Mediterraneans harbour) for aristocratic children. On of the moust famous black man what lives in Prague was Angelo Solimar (1721-1796;https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelo_Soliman). He was a servent of Lichtensteins, suppost to be friend with Mozart. For other discovery of black people in Bohemian history was occasional ( for example on coronation ceremony of Maxmillien the second) and it was only an attraction for people. This days (2018) Bohemia is content with wave of racism leaded by czech-japanise Tomio Okamura and his political party SPD.